# OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use Running Flask Application on Apache2

Tags: python, flask, apache2

I have my flask code in **app.py**

```
/some code//


if __name__ == '__main__':
     app.run()
```

and i have set up my **wsgi file** as in the path `/var/www/AutomateTests`

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.6


import sys
import logging

sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/AutomateTests/")

from app import app as application
application.root_path = '/var/www/AutomateTests/'
```

and I have `/etc/apache2/sites-available/automate_tests.conf`

```
VirtualHost *:80>
                ServerName htstool.arubanetworks.com
                ServerAdmin admin@htstool.arubanetworks.com
                ServerAlias htstool.arubanetworks.com
                ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/hts-error.log
                CustomLog /var/log/apache2/htstool-access.log combined
                WSGIDaemonProcess AutomateTests user=www-data group=www-data threads=5
                WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/AutomateTests/automate_tests.wsgi
                <Directory /var/www/AutomateTests>
                WSGIProcessGroup AutomateTests
                WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
                Order allow,deny
                        Allow from all
                </Directory>
                LogLevel info
</VirtualHost>
```

I have set up everything rightly and i have been stuck on this problem for weeks now. Can someplease help me on how to bring it up on the server. Is there a step i am missing.

im setting the same error of my port is in use although ITS NOT! 
See the picture of my error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUKWH.png)

But as you can see my ports are empty and not being used. I check that using the command `netstat -ntlp`

[see my ports are listening and not established](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KWcN0.png)

Can someone please please help me. I am stuck and don't mark it as already answered before checking it completely. I have tried all the answers and they don't work! Please be patient and let others help me because I can't do it myself.

My server is running fine and I'm seeing the default ubuntu page which means that my apache2 server is working fine so there is something wrong with either the configuration or my ports

Answer (score 0):

Two things come to mind when I see this.

1. Do you have Apache installed and running on the server? Apache may be listening on port 80 and preventing your Python script from binding to that port, but the way you ran netcat won't show this. You can check this at [sever_ip]:80.

   > But as you can see my ports are empty and not being used. I check that using the command netstat -ntlp

Note the first line of output from that command: `(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)` Apache runs with elevated privileges, so you'll need to run as root (append `sudo` to the beginning of your command) to see its port binding. I'd bet that this is the issue. Once this is fixed, you may run in to the following issue:

2. Are you running the script as root? On Linux, you need to use sudo to bind to ports 0 through 1024 (as explained [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/16568)).

One more thing, not related to the script specifically, but it looks like you're using AWS EC2 in the screenshots (correct me if I'm wrong). If you want to be able to reach the instance on port 80 from the public internet, you'll need to make sure you [allow it in the Security Group](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html). I know this can cause some confusion for people using AWS EC2 for the first time, sure did for me.

Hope this helps!